# C# Arbitrarily Nested IEnumerable object

Tags: c#, ienumerable

I am trying to write some methods to deal with multi-layered IEnumerable object in C#. The following example is the method named "ConsoleWrite" which used for printing each string in IEnumerable object to console.

```
public void ConsoleWrite(IEnumerable<string> StringData)
{
    foreach (var EachString in StringData)
    {
        Console.Write(EachString);
    }
}
```

The usage of "ConsoleWrite" method.

```
List<string> Test1 = new List<string>();
Test1.Add("123");
Test1.Add("456");
ConsoleWrite(Test1);
```

It works well and the output is "123456". However, when it comes to the `List<List<string>>` case, this ConsoleWrite method needs to be overloading as below.

```
public void ConsoleWrite(IEnumerable<IEnumerable<string>> StringData)
{
    foreach (var EachString in StringData)
    {
        ConsoleWrite(EachString);
    }
}
```

The test of the case `List<List<string>>`.

```
List<List<string>> Test2 = new List<List<string>>();
Test2.Add(Test1);
Test2.Add(Test1);
ConsoleWrite(Test2)
```

Furthermore, for the case `List<List<List<string>>>`, this ConsoleWrite method needs to be overloading as `public void ConsoleWrite(IEnumerable<IEnumerable<IEnumerable<string>>> StringData)`. I am wondering that is there any way to deal with arbitrarily nested List `IEnumerable<...<IEnumerable<string>>>` easily and without overloading one-by-one?

Any suggestions are welcome.

Comment: Instead of writing overloads you could change the data to work with your first method.  Like for a `List<List<string>>` you'd pass `ConsoleWrite(listOfList.SelectMany(x => x))`. And for `List<List<List<string>>>` it would be `ConsoleWrite(listOfListOfList.SelectMany(x => x.SelectMany(y => y)))`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could just the non generic `IEnumerable`, some *pattern matching* and *recursion*

```
public static void ConsoleWrite(IEnumerable source)
{
   foreach (var item in source)
      if (item is string str)
         Console.WriteLine(str);
      else if (item is IEnumerable enumerable)
         ConsoleWrite(enumerable);
}
```

**Example**

```
var list = new List<string> {"1", "2", "3"};

ConsoleWrite(list);

var list2 = new List<List<string>>
   {
      new List<string>(){"4", "5", "6"},
      new List<string>(){"7", "8", "9"}
   };

ConsoleWrite(list2);
```

**Output**

```
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
```

[**Full Demo here**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/O5oOW3)

---

Another more *generic* way would be to create an *extension method*, Like `SelectMany` with *recursion*

```
public static class Extensions
{
   public static IEnumerable<T> FlattenMany<T>(this IEnumerable source)
   {
      foreach (var item in source)
         if (item is T t)
            yield return t;
         else if (item is IEnumerable enumerable)
            foreach (var elem in enumerable.FlattenMany<T>())
               yield return elem;
   }
}
```

**Usage**

```
var list2 = new List<List<string>>
{
   new List<string>() {"4", "5", "6"},
   new List<string>() {"7", "8", "9"}
};

var results = list2.FlattenMany<string>();
```